# Android unable to extend a webview

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview

I have a class that rotates a webview in C#/Xamarin.

here is the code for that:

```
public class VerticalWebView : WebView
{
    bool topDown = true;

    public VerticalWebView(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    public VerticalWebView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {

    }

    public VerticalWebView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    {
    }

    public VerticalWebView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
    {
    }

    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        if (topDown)
        {
            canvas.Translate(Height, 0);
            canvas.Rotate(90);
        }
        else
        {
            canvas.Translate(0, Width);
            canvas.Rotate(-90);
        }

        canvas.ClipRect(0, 0, Width, Height, Region.Op.Replace);
        base.Draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

then i looked in my manifest file to determine the package name in order to package qualify the item in the XML.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="MyCwiCardApp.MyCwiCardApp" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <application android:label="MyCwiCardApp">
    <activity android:name=".CwiLogInActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".CardDisplayActivity" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

as you can see here that name is : MyCwiCardApp.MyCwiCardApp

here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <MyCwiCardApp.MyCwiCardApp.VerticalWebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
  </MyCwiCardApp.MyCwiCardApp.VerticalWebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

now whenever i launch the program it crashes with an inflation exception saying that it is unable to inflate my layout.

Most of the responses to this problem are all focused on ensuring that the constructors are present in the overloaded class, or making sure that the name is package qualified in the XML. As you can see I am clearly doing this. I have tried prefacing with com, and also just using one CwiMyCardApp, neither solved the issue.

Comment: You should be following Java notation of `my.package.Class` in your XML definition. You should also use the `[Register]` / `[Export]` tag above your `WebView` class to ensure it's properly registered in the dexlist instead of having a md5 hash.

Comment: Secondly, you didn't add the namespace of your control in your post, but by default you should be able to find it in the `obj\Debug\android\src` folder and it will let you know the proper namespace needed. If you register/export it, it will be much more maintainable than a md5 hash.